# Compute the distribution of $(X,Y)$ where $X = \sqrt{U}\cos(2\pi V)$ and $Y = \sqrt{U} \sin(2\pi V)$

Tags: random-variables, density-function

Let $U \sim \mathcal{E}(1)$ (exponential random variable with parameter $1$) and $V$ a uniform distributed random variable on $(0,1)$.

We assume that $U$ and $V$ are independent.

Define $X: = \sqrt{U}\cos(2\pi V)$ and $Y: = \sqrt{U} \sin(2\pi V)$.

I have to compute the distribution of $(X,Y)$.

Now what they do is the following:

Let $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be measurable.

$\mathbb{E}[\phi(X,Y)] = \int_0^{+\infty} \int_0^1 \phi(\sqrt{u} \cos(2\pi v), \sqrt{u} \sin(2\pi v)) e^{-u} du dv$

I don't how to derive this, the remaining steps are clear to me. I'm aware of the formula:

$\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \int_Ef(X) d \mathbb{P}_X(X)$ but I don't how this was applied to my case.

I know that the denisty of $U$ is $e^{-x}$ and the one of $V$ is $1_{[0,1]}$ (indicator function). And since $U$ and $V$ are by assumption independent we have that the density of $(U,V)$ is $e^{-x}1_{[0,1]}$ (the product of the two densities).

Comment: The "parameter" of the exponential distribution is not well defined. Some people use the means, others its reciprocal. In this case it is ok because they coincidence, but be aware in general to specify the _mean_ and not the "parameter."

Comment: Notice that $(X, Y)$ is uniform rotation followed by a scaling by $U.$ Maybe using this decomposition you get your answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

Let $\varphi :(0,\infty )\times (0,1)\to \mathbb R^2$ defined by $\varphi (u,v)=(\sqrt u\cos(2\pi v),\sqrt u\sin(2\pi v))$, i.e. $(X,Y)=\varphi (U,V)$.

$$\mathbb P\{(X,Y)\in B\}=\mathbb P\{(U,V)\in \varphi ^{-1}(B)\}=\int_{\varphi ^{-1}(B)}f_{(U,V)}(u,v)dudv=\int_Bf_{(U,V)}(\varphi ^{-1}(x,y))|J_{\varphi ^{-1}(x,y)}|dxdy.$$

Therefore $$f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=f_{(U,V)}(\varphi ^{-1}(x,y))|J_{\varphi ^{-1}(x,y)}|,$$

where $J_{g(s,t)}$ denote the jacobian of the function $g$ at $(s,t)$. Just compute $\varphi ^{-1}$ and you are done.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right, but I got: $g^{-1}(x,y) = ((\frac{x}{\cos (2 \pi \frac{arctan(\frac{y}{x})}{2\pi}}))^2, \frac{arctan(\frac{y}{x})}{2 \pi})$. Is that correct?

Comment: @MyGanton: no it's not true. [check wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates)

Comment: According to wiki it would be $g^{-1} = (x^2+y^2, arctan(\frac{y}{x})/(2\pi))$?

Comment: still wrong @MyGanton

Comment: I don't see why, because if I compute $x^2+y^2$ I get $u$ and for $arctan(y/x)/(2\pi)$ I do get $v$.@joshua